# Having an issue with Unilink for Deeplinking - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I am following below link to implement deeplinking in my flutter application:

[Uni Link](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-deep-linking-flutter-uni-links/)

I have done everything as same suggested there.
Below is my Intent filter inside Android manifest file:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="unilinks.example.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Application is launched successfully, But when I am writing url in my device browser as `"https://unilinks.example.com"`, It should open the app installed but it just displays **"This site can't be reached"** !

What might be the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by awesome Firebase Dynamic link:

Uploading my youtube video on it soon so till than take care and you can check for Firebase Dynamic links. Belive me It works.

Comment: Can you please share the solution/link to the video/tutorial on how you achieved this?